# Swift: Speed limit for a particular location on MapKit or Google Maps?

Tags: swift, google-maps, geolocation, mapkit, xcode8

I just want please a way to know the speed limit in the touched location on the map (MapKit or Google Maps) in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits) provides the *speed limit* for a given road segment. A warning about data fidelity:

> The accuracy of speed limit data returned by the Google Maps Roads API cannot be guaranteed. The speed limit data provided is not real-time, and may be estimated, inaccurate, incomplete, and/or outdated.

The bad news is that you need a [Google Maps APIs Premium Plan](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/) to use it.

Please checkout the links above for further details.

Comment: So map kit does not support this feature ?

Comment: @Nour There is no functionality in MapKit for retrieving speed limits.